# What is the earliest recorded example of an extradition treaty or law?

Tags: law, ancient-egypt, ancient-china, treaties

While reading a news article on someone being extradited from overseas to face justice in the U.S. it started me thinking about the history of the extradition process.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extradition) and [The History Vault](https://www.thehistoryvault.co.uk/extradition-a-history/) both mention extradition (also known as *[rendition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendition_(law))*) as being ancient concepts. Wikipedia dates it back to the 13 century BCE:

> when an Egyptian Pharaoh, Ramesses II, negotiated an extradition treaty with Hittite King, Hattusili III.

The History Vault also cites Ramses II, but *hints* at more about the ancient origins of extradition practices:

> As a concept, it originated with the Ancient Egyptian **and Chinese civilisations.** Following an unsuccessful Hittite  invasion of Egypt, an extradition agreement formed part of a peace treaty signed between Ramses II and the Hittite King, Hattusili II. Amazingly, this text still exists. [*emphasis mine*]

The ancient Egyptian example is clearly cited by both sources, but I have not yet been able find a specific reference to an example of ancient Chinese extradition / rendition practices or treaties.  Thus I don't know if the ancient Chinese example(s) are from the same, or an earlier, or a later time frame.  The History Vault article says no more about it than the highlighted portion cited above.

Do the ancient Chinese origins pre-date the documented example from ancient Egypt?

Comment: It must have been about dissidents and contenders to the monarch's power, rather than fugitives from criminal justice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can find no references to an extradition treaty earlier than the Egypt/Hittite one that you mention.  A number of sources beyond Wikipedia describe it as the most ancient.

As an example:

Kai I. Rebane in their [Extradition and Individual Rights: The Need for an International Criminal Court to Safeguard Individual Rights](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/19ce/2b6d0ef381fcf0b4bc5e66f8e1cf7ba6650b.pdf) published by *Fordham International Law Journal* in 1995 states:

> **The Roots of Extradition**
>
> The practice of extradition originated in the ancient middle- and far-eastern civilizations as a matter of
> courtesy and good will between sovereigns. The earliest recorded
> extradition treaty dates to 1280 B.C., between Ramses II, the Pharaoh
> of Egypt, and King Hattusli III of the Hittites, and provided for the
> mutual return of criminals. The first, similar provision appeared in
> western Europe in 1174 A.D., between Henry II of England and William
> the Lion, King of Scotland. Over the following centuries, however,
> extradition remained an ad hoc arrangement between sovereigns,
> performed as a need arose. *During the seventeenth to nineteenth
> centuries, the Chinese Qing State extradited criminals* from
> neighboring Korea, Vietnam, and Burma on the basis of reciprocity. The
> Chinese authorities extended their control over the rendition process
> by instructing the returned individual's government as to the proper
> method of punishment.

Emphasis mine.

Kabine in turn cites *[Imperial China's Border Control Law](https://heinonline.org/HOL/LandingPage?handle=hein.journals/colas1&div=12&id=&page=)* by R. Randle Edwards to which I do not have access.

Based on this citation it seems unlikely the the Chinese extraditions were older than the Egyptian ones.